# What is the Difference Between Tax Class : Texable Goods And Shipping

Tags: magento2, tax, shipping-tax

In my store i set shipping rates for individual states and countries based on zipcodes. Pls guide me what i select in the stage of tax class.

Comment: You can get more information from here : https://custommagentodevelopmentindia.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/complete-guide-to-setup-and-manage-taxes-in-magento-magento-development/

Answer (score 0):

**Product Tax Class** is a type of Product that is being purchased. When you create a Product, you will assign a Product Tax Class to that Product.

Magento comes with two Product Tax Classes:**Taxable Goods and Shipping**.

The **class Shipping is applied to shipping charges** because some places charge sales tax on shipping. If your customer's sales tax is different for different types of Products, then you will need to create a Product Tax Class for each type of Product.

You can refer below links for more information

1. [link](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-create-tax-rule-magento)
2. [link](http://coolblueweb.com/blog/configuring-shipping-taxes-in-magento/)